# Trying to figure out what this is on window

Tags: windows, window-frame

Trying to figure out what this is on my window. It’s horizontal clear strip that slightly opens. At first thought it was some sort of weep hole, but it seems too big. It’s in the middle part of the window and near the lock but not connected in anyway to the lock.

[image]

Comment: Off hand would think a required or bonus ventilation stripe for newer(40years) well sealed houses to let some fresh air in.

Comment: We’re also in Washington state. The house was built in the late 90s. No AC. When you open this portion the crack is very small the picture shows as much as it will open.

Comment: Late 90s is when houses started to become more air tight and stuffy.  A tiny bit of fresh air at windows might have been found helpful.  Not sure how good the house air exchangers were back then, since almost new idea.

Comment: Also called a trickle vent - now mandatory in the UK for all windows